# Get a routing parameter in Twig template (which is not in query)?

Tags: symfony, routes, twig

Is it possible to get a parameter in a Twig template which is not in the query without having to pass it through the controller ?

The idea would be to access the `section` value from a routing like this one (to avoid long Twig conditions to add "active" CSS classes in template menus) :

```
ibcpg_admin_dashboard:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: IBCPGAdministrationBundle:Main:dashboard, section: dashboard }

ibcpg_admin_courses:
    path:     /courses
    defaults: { _controller: IBCPGAdministrationBundle:Course:list, section: courses }

ibcpg_admin_course_add:
    path:     /course/add
    defaults: { _controller: IBCPGAdministrationBundle:Course:add, section: courses }

ibcpg_admin_course_edit:
    path:     /course/edit/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: IBCPGAdministrationBundle:Course:edit, section: courses }
    requirements:
        id: \d+

ibcpg_admin_course_delete:
    path:     /course/delete/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: IBCPGAdministrationBundle:Course:delete, section: courses }
    requirements:
        id: \d+

ibcpg_admin_course_chapters:
    path:     /course-chapters
    defaults: { _controller: IBCPGAdministrationBundle:CourseChapter:listAndAdd, section: course_chapters }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that all parameters defined directly within `defaults` table (in routing) are filling the attributes part of the [ParameterBag](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html), so you can access them like this in Twig templates :

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('my_parameter') }}
```

`my_parameter` would be replace by `section` for the example I gave.